What is the Economic Orientation of Hegel? Is he a Capitalist, Socialist, or Communist?
What is the Economic Orientation of Hegel? Is he a Capitalist, Socialist or  Communist?
What is his point of view regarding commerce, and principal of supply and demand?
What is his point of view regarding feudalism?

Habib calls Hegel a "philosopher of capitalism", "the first major philosopher to offer a direct and sustained treatment of capitalism, which he called "bourgeois" or civil "society"". MacGregor gives a more nuanced view in The Communist Ideal in Hegel and Marx and other books, but even he does not quite make him a socialist, more like corporate capitalist, perhaps. Here is his interview.
